# Make tf.function error on compilation failure

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tensorflow`s `tf.function` converts a function to a graph representation using `Autograph`, but it can't convert all code. If it fails it will throw a *warning* ("tensorflow will run this code as-is..."). Is there any way to make the program *error*? That way I can be sure all my functions were successfully converted to graph mode if no error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py), there seems to be an environment variable called `AUTOGRAPH_STRICT_CONVERSION` which you can set to some integer value higher than zero to force autograph to raise an error in case that the conversion could not be performed. I could not find a reference in the documentation to this, so it might be either removed in the future or replaced as a more accessible feature in the API, but for know you can enable it with something like this at the beginning of your code:

```py
import os
os.environ['AUTOGRAPH_STRICT_CONVERSION'] = '1'

# TensorFlow code...
```